# How to get a Page instance outside of xaml.cs in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have created a Page named Page1.xaml.
Now I have Page1.xaml and the code behind Page1.xaml.cs.

It is obvious to use "this" to reference the Page1 instance in Page1.xaml.cs. But what if I have a Commond.cs file to store my commands,and I want to access controls in this file? How can I refer to the Page1 instance? Thanks.

Comment: if your command class is not a static means, you can send your page instance to Command class via constructor.

Answer (score 1):

When you step out of Page1.xaml, then you are out of the scope, hence the only way to access things in Commond.cs is to implement the needed code in a class that can be shared by both cs files

Comment: So you mean it is not possible to access the controls while in another .cs file?

Answer (score -1):

I guess your idea to create independent Command.cs is to put all the action/command in as separate class. Which looks quite good. So basically you can create a command repository where you can register all your commands.

Let see this with an example:

```
public static class AppCommandRepository {
    public static ICommand YourCommand { get; private set; }
    // You can also register other command as well.
    internal static void Initialize()
    {
        YourCommand = new YourCommand();                   
    }
}
```

Now in xaml

```
<Button Command="Commands:AppCommandRepository.YourCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding}" /> !--Here commands is a namespace reference in xaml which is pointing to command repo.
```

In YourCommand.cs implement the `ICommand` interface. Make sure that in overided execute method you have passed the parameter of Page1 class. 
Like this:

```
void ICommand.Execute(Page1 parameter){}
```

Now as you have passed the commandParamter from Page1 file, when user hits the button click event then Page1 reference will come as a parameter to the execute method. Also make sure you initialized you command repository as the entry point of the app. I guess the question that you asked is much broader, and there can be multiple implementations for this. 
Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,and indeed this works for ICommand. But Is it possible to do this in Command.cs var s=page1.textBox.Text? Or like Alrehamy said, it is not possible to access controls' attributes directly like this?

Comment: the question specifies how to access directly a control's attributes not via repository

Comment: Not sure u guys are aware of the MVVM or not. But this is not the way to access a UI element from other .cs file. As i said u can still pass the reference of Page1.xaml as a commandparameter. With that you can also access the UI element if u want.